# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i'm trying to create db server on Spring, and  looked through a lot of similar questions, but no one answer to them can't help me. I can't solve this Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'groupController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gs'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'groupServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gr'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1a3c15e0' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1a3c15e0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

So here's my classes :

**GroupController.java**

```
 @RestController
public class GroupController {

    @Autowired
    private GroupService gs;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/groups", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Group> getAllGroups(){
       // return mocklist();
        return gs.getAll();
    }

    private List<Group> mocklist() {
        Group g= new Group();
        g.setId(1);
        g.setGroupName("333");
        g.setTutorName("shcefsa");
        List<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
        list.add(g);
        g.setId(2);
        g.setGroupName("333");
        g.setTutorName("shc321efsa");
        list.add(g);
        return list;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/groups/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Group getGroupById(@PathVariable("id") int groupId){
        return gs.getById(groupId);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/groups", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Group addGroup(@RequestBody Group group){
        return gs.add(group);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/groups", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Group updateGroup(@RequestBody Group group){
        return gs.add(group);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/groups/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void deleteGroup(@PathVariable("id") int groupId){
        gs.deleteById(groupId);
    }


}
```

**GroupRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Integer> {


}
```

**GroupService.java**

```
@Service
public interface GroupService {

    List<Group> getAll();
    Group getById(int id);
    Group add(Group group);
    void deleteById(int id);

}
```

**GroupServiceImpl.java**`

```
@Service
public class GroupServiceImpl implements GroupService {
@Autowired
private GroupRepository gr;

public List<Group> getAll() {
    return gr.findAll();
}

public Group getById(int id) {
    return gr.findOne(id);
}

public Group add(Group group) {
    return gr.save(group);
}

public void deleteById(int id) {
    gr.delete(id);
}
```

Looking at other answers, it seems that everything is fine, but it's obvious that there's an error. Hope you'll help me

**UPDATE**

**Databaseconfig.java**

```
    @Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.homestudio.tutor.server.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.homestudio.tutor.server")
public class DatabaseConfig {


    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("db.entity.package"));
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return em;
    }



    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());

        return manager;

    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));

        ds.setInitialSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.initialSize")));
        ds.setMinIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.minIdle")));
        ds.setMaxIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.maxIdle")));
        ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Long.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMilles")));
        ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Long.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.minEvictableIdleTimeMilles")));
        ds.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("db.testOnBorrow")));
        ds.setValidationQuery(env.getRequiredProperty("db.validationQuery"));

        return ds;

    }

    public Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.properties");

        properties.load(is);

            return properties;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find file \"hibernate.properties\" in classpath");
        }



    }
}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.homestudio.tutor.server")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));


        converters.add(converter);

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the main part here is "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available". Looks like your GroupRepository required some spring-data-jpa to be initialized. Can you provide your spring context definition?

Comment: @Normal This is new for me and I do not fully understand concept. It's about ServletContext?

Comment: No, I mean main spring framework configuration. Generally it is '@Configuration' or '@SpringBootApplication' annotated classes or spring xml file.

Comment: @Normal i added this classes

Comment: Try to rename method name "entityManagerFactoryBean" into "entityManagerFactory". Does it work?

Comment: @Normal now i got this error `BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'`

Comment: @Normal everything was working until i add services and repositories. I had only controller with 1 method and mock data

Comment: well I've created a sample project based on your sources and the problem was gone after method renaming. Do you have an opportunity to create a mock project which reproduced that problem and share it (via github for example) ?